# Asp.net MVC get action name when we have multiple submit buttons in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have some dynamic roles in my Asp.Net MVC project and I need to get current requested action name to authorize.
Because I have multiple submit buttons in some of views , when I want to get "Create" or "Edit" action name, I take "Action" instead of that.
I try this code :

```
var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
```

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the action name from the `RouteData`

```
var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Comment: Not responding, I still Have that problem